# Recursive function through array until the end

Tags: java

I have an array such as

```
int[] array = {4,1,1,1,1,4};
```

The first 4 signifies that there are 4 numbers to be calculated, and the last 4 signifies that we need to find a combination of operations to achieve that number.

I want to make the loop stop when I reach the last 1, or in general the number before the last in the array. Usually this is easy, however when all the numbers are the same, finding the index of one of them at the end is difficult ... suggestions?

I usually use:

```
int last_num = integers[integers.length-2];


if(last_num == integers[a]){ System.out.println(Total); )
```

However if last_num = 1, and integers[a] =1, then it can stop after the first time going through the loop.

Same thing occurs if trying to find the index using binarySearch due to all the numbers being the same..

Recursive Function (note I am new to Java and I'm sure I'm using the function wrong because I'm just returning a true everytime, however my goal is to have it run and print out the values I want - please excuse that for now):

```
public static boolean addMoreMore(int a , double b , String c, int[] integers , int target, double possible2, int last_num){
  int counter = 0;
  char[] symbols1 = {'+' , '-' , '*','/'};            
  for(int z = 0; z<4; z++){
        char operator = symbols1[z];

        String what1 = ""; 
        double total1 = 0;            

        if(operator == '+'){
            total1 = b + integers[a];
            what1 = c + "+" + integers[a];  //System.out.println(what1);    
            if(last_num  != integers[a]){
                //System.out.println("ACTIVATE1");
                addMoreMore(a+1 , total1, what1, integers, target, possible2, last_num);
         }
        else {
            if(total1 == target){
                System.out.println(what1 + " = " + total1);     
            }
        }
  }    
        else if(operator == '-'){

            total1 = b - integers[a];
            what1 = c + "-" + Integer.toString(integers[a]);       
            //System.out.println(what1);                                   

            if(last_num  != integers[a]){
                //     System.out.println("ACTIVATE2");
                addMoreMore(a+1 , total1, what1, integers, target, possible2, last_num);  
            }
            else {
                if(total1 == target){
                    System.out.println(what1 + " = " + total1);
                }          
            }
      }
      else if(operator == '*'){
          total1 = b * integers[a];
          what1 = c + "*" + Integer.toString(integers[a]);  
          //System.out.println(what1);                                

          if(last_num  != integers[a]){
              //       System.out.println("ACTIVATE3");
              addMoreMore(a+1 , total1, what1, integers, target, possible2, last_num);       
          }
          else{
              if(total1 == target){
                  System.out.println(what1 + " = " + total1);
              }   
          }
     }
     else if(operator == '/'){
         total1 = b / integers[a];
         what1 = c + "/" + Integer.toString(integers[a]); // System.out.println(what1);  
         if((b % integers[a]) == 0){

             if(last_num  != integers[a]){
                 // System.out.println("ACTIVATE4");
                addMoreMore(a+1 , total1, what1, integers, target, possible2, last_num);  
             }
          else {
              if(total1 == target){
                  System.out.println(what1 + " = " + total1);    
              }
          }
      }    
  }         
}
return true;       
}
```

Comment: I'm glad YOU "want to make a recursive function that stops at the last 1", only I don't see your attempt...

Comment: Don't use the contents of the array, keep track of your position within the array.

Comment: Why not simply use `if (integers.length - 2 == a)` ?

Comment: If you are using a recursive method (which you have not enclosed in your question for some reason), then when calling this function, pass your array AS WELL AS the current index that it is supposed to "work on". Your recursion-stop condition should then be `if (index == array.length-1 (or 2 or whatever you wish)`

Comment: @Tdorno the code is very long because the recursive portion relies on another section. Don't worry, I am working on it.

Comment: @ChthonicProject - the problem is lets say the array was 6 2 4 3 3 2 3 24 - then integers.length-2 would equal 3 and then it would stop at the first 3 (because 2*4*3 = 24, therefore the condition is met)

Comment: @Ds.109 : You hadn't added the rest of the code back then, so I thought `a` was the index you were looping over. As Jim Garrison says, you need to only use the position, not the content.

Comment: @ChthonicProject - That's what I want to do- use the position, but how can I do that ... the solutions I found fail due to the repetition of values... is there something like indexOf to return the position and not the value at that position?

Comment: Overloading an array/collection like that is a bad idea.  Have the last 4 as a separate parameter, and drop the initial 4 (you can infer number of array elements you have to process by looking at length of array).  Arrays should be arrays of one type of thing, e.g. colours, pixels, heights of buildings, etc...).  Mixing is a nightmare to keep track of and leads to unmaintainable spaghetti code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a comment stated, compare the **index position of the array** instead of the value.

For example:

Instead of

```
if(last_num == integers[a]){ System.out.println(Total); )
```

Try

```
if(integers.length - 2 == a) { System.out.println(Total); }
```

Assuming `a` is a counting variable for the index position in your array.

Comment: Possible - problem is how do I count through this. The idea is I have to go through all the possible combinations of operations with the same order of numbers - i.e. if I have 3 4 5 , then I have to try 3+4+5, 3+4-5, 3+4*5, 3+4/5, 3-4+5, etc... So how could I count through that?

Comment: How can I get the position of integers[a] ?

Comment: @Ds.109 I'm not sure how to answer your first problem, seeing as I'm not trying to solve your entire algorithm. The focus of my answer is just to show you how to check when you're at the last number. And the position of `integers[a]` is just `a`

Comment: ... You actually solved my confusion with that comment. integers[a] is just a... i can't believe I missed that. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Q21175220 {
    static enum Operation {
        ADD,
        SUBTRACT,
        MULTIPLY,
        DIVIDE
    }

    public static void getValidOperations
    (
        final ArrayList<Operation[]> validOperations,
        final LinkedList<Operation> operations,
        final int[] values,
        final int desired_total
    )
    {
        if ( operations.size() < values.length - 1 )
        {
            operations.addLast( Operation.ADD );
            getValidOperations( validOperations, operations, values, desired_total );
            operations.removeLast();
            operations.addLast( Operation.SUBTRACT );
            getValidOperations( validOperations, operations, values, desired_total );
            operations.removeLast();
            operations.addLast( Operation.MULTIPLY );
            getValidOperations( validOperations, operations, values, desired_total );
            operations.removeLast();
            operations.addLast( Operation.DIVIDE );
            getValidOperations( validOperations, operations, values, desired_total );
            operations.removeLast();
        } else {
            int i = 0;
            int total = values[i];
            for ( Operation op : operations )
            {
                ++i;
                switch ( op )
                {
                case ADD:       total += values[i]; break;
                case SUBTRACT:  total -= values[i]; break;
                case MULTIPLY:  total *= values[i]; break;
                case DIVIDE:    total /= values[i]; break;
                }
            }
            if ( total == desired_total )
                validOperations.add( operations.toArray( new Operation[ values.length - 1 ] ) );
        }
    }

    public static String calculationToString
    (
        final Operation[] operations,
        final int[] values
    )
    {
        final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        int i = 0;
        buffer.append( values[i] );
        for ( Operation op : operations )
        {
            switch ( op )
            {
            case ADD:       buffer.append('+'); break;
            case SUBTRACT:  buffer.append('-'); break;
            case MULTIPLY:  buffer.append('*'); break;
            case DIVIDE:    buffer.append('/'); break;
            }
            buffer.append( values[++i] );
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }

    public static void test
    (
        final int[] values,
        final int desired_total
    )
    {
        final ArrayList<Operation[]> validOperations = new ArrayList<Operation[]>();
        getValidOperations( validOperations, new LinkedList<Operation>(), values, desired_total );
        for ( Operation[] ops: validOperations )
            System.out.println( calculationToString( ops, values ) + " = " + desired_total );
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test( new int[]{ 1, 1, 1, 1 }, 4 );
        test( new int[]{ 1, 1, 1, 2, 5 }, 10 );
    }
}
```